# Recyclerview with center item decorated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can anyone pls guide me on how to achieve the below given design in android. I need to use recyclerview and on clicking the item it should be centered like in image.

[Click here to view the design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKM09.png)

I have been trying to solve this but couldn't achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your code in a minimal, yet complete and verifiable version.

Answer (score 0):

Make the layout of the adapter (recyclerview). Use linear layout with orientation horizontal, now according to your requirement you can add images/textview etc inside the layout and if you want to overlap (means view over view) you can use frame layout and for border you can use shape with stroke in drawable folder by creating a layout file or another way is, you can declare a view and give background color to it.